# sharepoint error 0x80070024 operation is prohibited

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2010

trying update properties of an existing document on sharepoint list, using java SOAP web services
sharepoint response

> The
>   attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the administrator.Operations that exceed the
>   list view threshold are allowed in the following time window defined
>   by the administrator: <br/><b>Daily, from  7:00:00 PM to
>   10:00:00 AM . </b>
>                0x80070024

can't do any operations till the time mentioned? anyway to overcome this like searching more specific into a specific folder instead on list